# How do I configure Windows Live Writer with Blogger?

Tags: plugins, blogging, windows-live-writer

I know this is 2017 but I am still asking how can I configure Windows Live Writer with Blogger?

I've tried myself with my G+ profile and scoured the internet for post ( found, tried in vain )

I have Open Live Writer connected to blogger but there are no plugins available :-( therefore my question.

Any alternative to Open Live Writer which has a decent plugin ecosystem which integrates with Blogger?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't. Windows Live Writer won't support the authentication system, and Microsoft didn't offer an update so it could.

As for the plugins, I have no knowledge as I didn't use them with WLW or now with OLW.